# IIS returns 404 for second HttpPut and HttpDelete actions when it works fine on IIS Express

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api2, iis-express

I have a Web Api 2 Controller that looks like:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Users")]
public class UsersController : ApiController
{

  [HttpPut]
  [Route("permission/user")]
  public IHttpActionResult UpdateUserPermission(int id, string type, string name)
  {
  }

  [HttpPut]
  [Route("permission/admin")]
  public IHttpActionResult UpdateAdminPermission(int id, string name, string auth)
  {
  }

  [HttpDelete]
  [Route("permission/user")]
  public IHttpActionResult DeleteUserPermission(int id, string type)
  {
  }

  [HttpDelete]
  [Route("permission/admin")]
  public IHttpActionResult DeleteAdminPermission(int id, string name)
  {  
  }

}
```

When I call the endpoint PUT: api/Users/Permission/User?id=1&type=sometype&name=somename it works as expected. Same goes for the DELETE: api/Users/Permission/User?id=1&type=sometype

On the other hand, if I call the endpoint PUT: api/Users/Permission/Admin?id=1&name=somename&auth=someauth or DELETE: api/Users/Permission/Admin?id=1&name=somename it works on IIS Express, but IIS returns 404.

My route config looks as follows:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

I've looked at the IIS config, and specify the verbs to be handled is set to all verbs.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check IIS Express's log files to see which sub status is recorded for 404.

Comment: IIS is the one returning 404s, code is working fine on IIS Express. I'll try to see whether there is a sub-status in IIS logs since the browser is not capturing any.

Comment: I created a controller from your code and just did a return Ok(). I am using PostMan and was able to call all actions with your methods and received a status of 200 in each case. In other words, for some reason your code works perfectly for me. I know that this is probably not the answer but in your WebApiConfig.Register file but do you have the config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()  statement above the config.Routes.MapHttpRoute statement?

Comment: @Bill Yes, I do have config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes() above it. First of all, thanks for spending the time to try these endpoints. Unfortunately, that's my experience as well, it works fine on 3 machines, but when we deploy the code to production, IIS is returning 404.